# How can I call a shell script to start a backend Java process?

Tags: jenkins

After completing a Jenkins task, I execute a Linux shell script by using Jenkins' post-condition configuration section.

This Linux shell script wants to launch a standby service on the backend and can NOT cause Jenkins to pause.

I tried to use "nohup+&", etc., but it does not work.

Is there a good way to do it?

Comment: ensure that stderr is redirected too, ie ``nohup script.sh  2>&1 > /dev/null``

Comment: Could you still clarify what the problem is, exactly? Do you mean the build does not complete until the service exits? You would want the build to complete and leave the service running in the background?

Comment: to @sti, yes, it is.

Comment: @sti I have exactly the same problem, where I try to launch a background jar service with "nohup java -jar whatever &" but the Jenkins job won't exit until the jar exits, which is never does because it is a background service running all the time... Do you have a good solution for this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jenkins is probably waiting for some pipes to close. Your background process has inherited some file descriptors and is keeping them open for as long as it runs.

If you are lucky, the only file descriptors are 0, 1 and 2 (the standard ones.) You might want to check the file descriptors of the background process using `lsof -p PID` where PID is the process id of the background process.

You should make sure all of those file descriptors (both inputs and outputs) are redirected for the background process, so start it with something like:

```
nohup daemon </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Feel free to direct the output to a file other than `/dev/null` but make sure you keep the order of the redirections. The order is important.

If you plan to start background processes from a Jenkins job, be advised that Jenkins will kill background processes when build ends. See https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ProcessTreeKiller on how to prevent that.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with running a shell script from Jenkins as a background process. I fixed it by using the below command:

```
BUILD_ID=dontKillMe nohup ./start-fitnesse.sh &
```